# Numeric constant not valid in SQL

Tags: java, sql

I'm having a list object and im sending to SQL query as

```
UPDATE <table name> SET status= 'CLOSED' WHERE dlno IN ("+StringUtils.join(deals, ',')+") ";
```

My deals object is as follows

```
1549886508071HELMPFN
```

How can I pass a string here

```
[SQL0103] Numeric constant 1549886508071HELMPFN not valid.
```

Comment: You have to enclose it with `'`

Comment: `StringUtils.join()` makes me think "java", so I added that as a tag.  The question is really about the application language more than SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String constants need to be enclosed in single quotes.  In your case this would look like:

```
UPDATE <table name>
    SET status = 'CLOSED'
    WHERE dlno IN ('"+StringUtils.join(deals, "', '")  +"') ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Using bind variables will solve your quote problem and make your code safe against SQL injection:

```
    List<String> deals = ImmutableList.of("abc", "123", "def");
    StringBuilder questionMarks = new StringBuilder("?");
    for (int i=1;i<deals.size();i++) {
        questionMarks.append(",?");
    }
    Connection conn = ...; // presumably, you already have this
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
            "UPDATE my_table SET status= 'CLOSED' WHERE dlno IN (" + questionMarks + ")");
    for (int i=1;i<=deals.size();i++) { // note these are 1-indexed, not 0-indexed
        stmt.setString(i, deals.get(i-1));
    }
    stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Basically, you'll generate a query that says `UPDATE my_table SET status = 'CLOSED' WHERE dlno IN (?,?)` (the number of question marks corresponding to the number of parameters), and then you'll update them with `stmt.setString`. And then you can execute your update.

Also note you'll need to deal with `SQLException`s and closing the statement. Removed here for clarity.